# Java Observer и Observable

Tags: java, rxjava, observer

Только начинаю погружение в   Java. Не могу понять один момент, можем ли мы использовать один наблюдатель -  Observer для разных объектов наблюдения - Observable или должно быть строго, один Observer на один конкретный Observable? И Observable исполняется на каждую подписку или только один раз?

Answer (score 1):

Можем. И даже должны, если обработка событий от разных источников отличается несущественно. А сам источник события передается первым параметром в метод `update`. Если же обработчики принципиально различные, то лучше делать разные обработчики.